# How can i work with single Wallet having multiple addresses using web3Js?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I am new to cryptocurrency application development. I am using web3js library and reference is 
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html for managing wallet balance and multiple account address link with single wallet. How can i do this? 
We want every user deposit ether comes to out(application) wallet so we can reduce transaction charges as for individual it will many times(between our app, ethernet, user address, so on) from one account to other.

Answer (score 0):

Many exchanges implement an overlay SQL Database to manage account balances, as banks do.

The accounting API on bitcoin (or its' inheritance crypts) does not support that very well and it might get you confusing, which is why the accounting API has been deprecated.

You would need to:

- Allow users to register accounts at your database.
- Create an address using the [RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)) API, and associate it to the user logged in.
- Monitor the user balance by logging every transaction associated to his wallets.